# Probability mass function, Bernoulli RVs

Tags: probability, statistics, binomial-distribution

**The question:**

1) Verify whether this is True or False:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \left( \frac{k}{n} -p \right) {n \choose k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k} = 0
$$

2) This is not relevant to Q1.

The question is if $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ are Bernoulli (p) RVs, then the sum of all of them is a Binomial(n,p) RVs. Is this statement True or False?

**My attempt:**

1) I don't know how to derive the sum of the term $$\frac{k}{n} -p$$ 
Without this term, the sum of the other term is indeed the pmf of Binomial Distribution and it should be equal to 1 (I am not sure if it is a good idea to make it equal 1 straight away or if I have to manipulate it further somehow). And I guess this somehow cannot be equal to 0 (just guessing). But since I stuck with deriving the first term, I still can't conclude anything about the whole sum.

2) I know it looks true at first but it is indeed false since we missed the word ''independent''. My question is why the words independent Bernoulli RVs'' is so important here ?

ps: I am not sure what the green tick means (i am new to forum) since i appreciate anyone who helps me to answer but i realize i cannot tick for everyone so may i just vote up for everyone ? Is it ok?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a random variable having binomial distribution with parameters
$n$ and $p$.

Then:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\frac{k}{n}-p\right)\binom{n}{k}p^{k}\left(1-p\right)^{n-k}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}kP\left(X=k\right)-p\sum_{k=0}^{n}P\left(X=k\right)=\frac{1}{n}\mathsf{E}X-p=$$$$\frac{1}{n}np-p=0$$

2) These words are important because they insure that $X:=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$. If they are missing then for instance it is not excluded that we have $X_1=X_2=\cdots=X_n$ leading to a random variable $X=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ that only takes values in $\{0,n\}$, hence (for $n>1$) evidently not binomial.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If n>1, i think it should be Binomial, shouldn’t it?

Comment: By independence it is binomial. Otherwise it is not guaranteed as is shown in my answer . So the statement under 2 is false .

Answer (score 0):

I'll just answer the first question for now:

We have

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n ( \frac{k}{n}) {n \choose k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k} = \sum_{k=1}^n  {n-1 \choose k-1} p^k(1-p)^{n-k} = \sum_{j=0}^m {m \choose j} p^{j+1}(1-p)^{m-j} \\= p\sum_{j=0}^m {m \choose j} p^{j}(1-p)^{m-j} = p$$

so that indeed

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left( \frac{k}{n} -p\right) {n \choose k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \\= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{k}{n} {n \choose k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k} - p\sum_{k=0}^n  {n \choose k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k} = p-p= 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

> The question is if $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are Bernoulli ($p$) RVs, then the sum of all of them is a Binomial($n,p$) RVs. Is this statement True or False?

That is true if $X_1\ldots,X_n$ are independent. How best to prove it might depend on where you are in learning about these things.

If you know that $$\sum_{k=0}^n k \binom n k p^k (1-p)^{n-k} = np\tag 1$$ then that's most of what you need to do to answer your first question. As to how $(1)$ is proved, some algebra can do it, and there are also probabilistic arguments. But again I don't want to go into any of that without knowing where you are in the process of learning this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am currently in my second year undergrad study doing Stats. So obviously i’ve been starting to learn more abstract probability and statistics (my current particular unit of study) and learn how to prove things. Please explain whatever you think is enough for me to get that point.

Comment: A student in second-year undergraduate study can be at any of a great variety of different points in the process of learning a subject. That varies a lot from one student to another.

Comment: Please explain by some words. I’’ll try to get it :)

Comment: @tabitha96 : Are you aware of the fact that if $X \sim \operatorname{Binomial} (n,p)$ then $\Pr(X=k) = \dbinom n k p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$? Are you aware that $np = \text{the expected value of }X =\sum_{k=0}^n k \Pr(X=k) \text{ ?}$ If those things are familiar to you, then that tells me how I can explain this to you. If they're not, then we have to start in a different place.

Comment: Yes, I am, for sure I am aware of those things

Comment: @tabitha96 : So you have $$ np = \operatorname{E}(X) = \sum_{k=0}^n k\Pr(X=k) = \sum_{k=0}^n k\binom n k p^k (1-p)^{n-k}. $$ Therefore $$ 
\sum_{k=0}^n \left( \frac{k}{n} -p \right) {n \choose k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k} = \frac 1 n \sum_{k=0}^n k \binom n k p^k (1-p)^{n-k} - p \sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k p^k (1-p)^{n-k} $$ $$ = \frac 1 n \cdot np - p\cdot 1 = p - p = 0. $$

Comment: Oh I see. Yes, I got this proof. What I meant was the explanation of you for the independent of Bernoulli RVs. Sorry if it was confusing !

Comment: @tabitha96 : Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_6 \sim \operatorname{i.i.d.} \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p).$ Then what is $\Pr(X_1+\cdots+X_6 = 2) \text{?}$ It is the probability of the following event: $$\left\{ \begin{align} & X_1=X_2=1\ \&\ X_3=X_4=X_5=X_6 = 0 \\ \text{or } & X_1=X_3=1\ \&\ X_2=X_4=X_5=X_6=0 \\ \text{or } & X_1=X_4=1\ \&\ X_2=X_3=X_5=X_6=0 \\ \text{or } & \cdots \cdots \\ \vdots \\ \vdots \\ \vdots \end{align} \right.$$ The probability of the event on each line above is $p^2(1-p)^4.$ The number of lines is $\dbinom 6 2 = 15.$ So the probability that we seek is $\dbinom 6 2 p^2(1-p)^4.$

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation :)